# Adding OnItemSelectedListener to Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a button and a spinner (originally hidden). When user presses a button, spinner gets populated with items and becomes visible. Now I would like to add OnItemSelectedListener to the spinner. and I have tried many tutorials with no luck.

This is my OnCreate function

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button load_routes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load_routes);
    Spinner routes = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.routes_list);

    load_routes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            load_routes(v);
        }
    });

    routes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.v("routes", "route selected");
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            Log.v("routes", "nothing selected");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my load_routes function

```
private void load_routes(View v)
{
    Spinner routes = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.routes_list);
    List<String> routes_list = RouteParser.get_routes();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, routes_list);
    routes.setAdapter(adapter);

    TableRow list_of_routes_row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.list_of_routes_row);
    list_of_routes_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This set up does not work. The only way I got this to work is when I setup my listener as `routes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` Then I implement `OnItemSelectedListener` and include the functions neccessary. But I have multiple spinners and need to create separate listeners for different spinner. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why have you finded view again routes_list in load_routes() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your Spinner as field instantiate the listener once you do findViewById and use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
    final String[] s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.capteur_size);
    final EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCoC);

    spinnerCoC = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCoC);

    spinnerCoC.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            ed.setText(s2[arg2]);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }       

    });
```

Comment: You should explain your reasons for this solution